# Volume of a 3D square prism variation

Tags: geometry, volume

**Background**

I'm trying to calculate the volume of a shape that I don't know the name of. So, I'll describe the shape using an example.

Starting with a simple square prism - with a base of 1 x 1 and a height of 2, the 8 vertex points could be:

```
(x, y, z)
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 2
1, 0, 0
1, 0, 2
0, 1, 0
0, 1, 2
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 2
```

The shape I'm trying to work with only varies from this in the sense that the z values can be different for each vertex point:

```
(x, y, z)
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 2.25
1, 0, 0.1
1, 0, 2.5
0, 1, 0.2
0, 1, 2.75
1, 1, 0.3
1, 1, 3
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the name of this shape?
2. How do I calculate the volume of it?

Comment: Your shape is ill defined, because the two square "bases" are no more planar. To compute a volume, you should specify somehow which points belong to your solid. E.g.: you could take two points along the vertical axis of the shape and connect to each of them four vertices, in order to split each base into four triangles.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, you're right - thinking about my use case in more depth, the points most likely would be irregular and not in a plane. So, following your suggestion, the two points along the vertical axis would be (0.5, 0.5, z_top) and (0.5, 0.5, z_bottom). Would z_top and z_bottom just be the average of the z values of the four points on each end. Further, I would think the volumes of the four new shapes could be calculated similarly to what Reinhard has shown below. Average z value of the 3 points on each end, times the area of the cross-section on the xy plane (0.5 here)?

Comment: Sorry, the area would be 0.25 for each triangle, not 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, it must be guaranteed that your solid is well defined, i.e. that all four bottom vertices lie on a plane and all four top vertices lie on a plane. This means (assuming that the vertices always have the same order)
$$
z_1+z_7 = z_3+z_5 \\
z_2+z_8 = z_4+z_6
$$
which is true in your example. So I assume you were aware of that restriction.

Now we can simply use the height in the center of the solid to calculate the volume. The $z$-coordinates of the centers of the bottom face and the top face are:
$$
z_B = \frac{z_1+z_7}{2} = \frac{z_3+z_5}{2} = \frac{z_1+z_3+z_5+z_7}{4}
$$
and
$$
z_T = \frac{z_2+z_8}{2} = \frac{z_4+z_6}{2} = \frac{z_2+z_4+z_6+z_8}{4}
$$
and the volume is
$$
V= 1\cdot 1 \cdot |z_T - z_B| = |z_T - z_B|
$$
This can be shown e.g. by taking a second solid with the same shape, cut it into two pieces (perpendicular to the z-axis), flip the pieces and glue them at the corresponding bottom face and top face. The result will be a cuboid with a $1\times 1$ base and a height of $2|z_T - z_B|.$

By the way, I don't know if your solid has a special name.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your answer makes perfect sense. I was initially assuming the points were on a plane, but thinking about my use case more, they probably won't be. So, in the case with irregular end points, does Aretino's suggestion above seem like the best method to handle this situation?